# VBA function to use column name instead of cell address

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

There are two Excel sheets: `"Table"` and `"Formulas"`.

`"Table"` sheet has a table. Each column of this table has title in the first row, the other rows contain data and formulas.

`"Formulas"` sheet has a list of column addresses (A,B,C.. etc) with formula examples.

---

Imagine, this structure:

**"Table" sheet**

```
| A          | B              | C |
| -----------| ---------------|---|
| FirstNumber| SecondNumber   |Sum|
| 1          | 2              |3  |
```

**"Formulas"** sheet

```
| A        | B              | C                               |
| ---------| ---------------| --------------------------------|
| Cell     | SystemName     |Formula                          |
| A        |  FirstNumber   |                                 |
| B        |  SecondNumber  |                                 |
| C        |  Sum           |'=A{FirstNumber}+B{SecondNumber }|
```

---

Here we see, that the value of C cell in "Table" sheet should be the same as the value of C cell in "Formula" sheet. It is important, that the formula from "Formulas" sheet has SystemName, not a direct cell address.

So, I need to write a vba function   that check all formulas in "Table" sheet are correct after I save my document by comparing them with formulas in "Formulas" sheet. Additionally, every time I change the order of the columns in "Table" sheet it should not interrupt the check function because SystemNames are used in "Formulas" sheet, not direct cell addresses.

I understand, that I need to create an array with SystemNames and formulas and somehow compare them in for each loop. But I have no idea how to do it in VBA Excel.

Thank you

Comment: I have no idea, why github markdown doesn't render as it is supposed to. In preview tables look OK

Comment: Table sheet does not have title in first column or are FirstNumber and 1 titles?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution based on this table called Table1.  The solution requires Excel Office365 is dynamic arrays.

[image: Table of data]

On the Formulas sheet, enter the following formulas

`A2` is `=SUBSTITUTE(G2#,"2","")`

`B2` is `=TRANSPOSE(Table1[#Headers])`

`D2` is `=COLUMNS(Table1)`

`E2` is `=SEQUENCE(D2)`

`F2` is `=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FORMULATEXT(OFFSET(Table!A2,0,0,1,D2))),"")`

`G2` is `=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(2,E2#),"$","")`

Then use the following VBA code to fill in column C.

```
Sub ConvertFormula()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, count As Long
Dim newFormula() As Variant, celladdr() As Variant, letter() As Variant, systemName() As Variant

count = Range("D2").Value2
newFormula = Range("F2#").Value2
celladdr = Range("G2#").Value2
letter = Range("A2#").Value2
systemName = Range("B2#").Value2
For i = 1 To count
    If newFormula(i, 1) <> "" Then
        newFormula(i, 1) = "'" & newFormula(i, 1)
        For j = 1 To count
            newFormula(i, 1) = Replace(newFormula(i, 1), celladdr(j, 1), letter(j, 1) & "{" & systemName(j, 1) & "}")
            newFormula(i, 1) = Replace(newFormula(i, 1), "[@" & systemName(j, 1) & "]", letter(j, 1) & "{" & systemName(j, 1) & "}")
        Next j
    End If
Next i
Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(count + 1, 3)) = newFormula

End Sub
```

The code can handle formulas that use table references or cell references.  The final result is below.

[image]

Comment: Was does the # do/represent in e.g. `G2#` ?

Comment: G2# is the way Excel represents a dynamic array starting at G2.  IF it doesn't work then you probably have a version that doesn't support dynamic arrays.

Comment: Imteresting, but we can not add any formalas exept to the C cell in "Table" sheet. Anyway, thak you